# Cant group with aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I try to aggregate and group objects in mongodb by month. I basically copy query from mongo docs.

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { 
        $group : {
            _id: {
                month : { $month : "$registrationDate" }
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
);
```

Type of registrationDate is date.
Short version of object in users collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50ab08399b57f2be03000000"),
    ...
    "registrationDate" : ISODate("2012-11-20T05:34:01.000Z"),
    ...
}
```

Then I get an exception

```
exception: can't convert from BSON type NumberDouble to Date
```

Comment: It looks like in some where in your documents `registrationDate` was `double`.

Comment: Try running this query: `db.users.find({registrationDate:{ $type:1}})`. What do you get?

Comment: @Philipp, ty. Reason of exception is the type of several objects in db. Some object type is 18(Int64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have some documents in your collection where the type of `registrationDate` is not a date but a double-precision floating point number. You can find these documents with `db.users.find( { registrationDate: { $type:1 } } )`. Fix these documents and it should work. Alternatively you can add the following step to the front of your aggregation to exclude those documents where the registrationDate is not a Date: `{$match: { registrationDate: { $type:9 } } }`